# Volume of sphere using triple integration, centre not at origin.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I used spherical coordinate, but it came out too large and I got confused.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Does not matter where the center is, the volume is $4\pi r^3/3$. If you need help to prove it, please show us what the problem is, and what you have tried

Comment: @Dave my question is- volume of sphere with centre at 1, 2, 3 and radius 1 using triple integration

Answer (score 1):

Note that the volume does not change relative to you coordinate system.  Therefore we transpose the coordinate system so the sphere is centered at $(0,0,0)$ then integrate the sphere in the standered way.

$$
\int_0^\pi \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\text{the radius}} p sin(\phi)dpd\theta d\phi.
$$

Comment: I know centre doesn't matter here but I need to solve it using spherical coordinate. Or else will you explain with example, how to transpose the coordinate.